# How to link subquery in Laravel QueryBuilder to outer table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking on how I can have a subquery in Laravel QueryBuilder join with the outer table.  For instance, we have a table with Exchange Rates, with a currency and a value_date.

For each currency, we want to be able to fetch the valid exchange rate on a certain valuedate.  Since exchange rates do not change on non working days, that means that for saturday and sunday, the value of friday is still valid.   A bit of an obvious and standard case.

In SQL, I would query this as follows:

```
SELECT currency, value_date, rate
FROM exchange_rates er
WHERE value_date = (
    SELECT max(value_date)
    FROM exchange_rates
    WHERE currency = er.currency
    AND value_date <= '2019-02-03'
)
```

This would return a list of all exchange rates (one record for each currency), with the rate that is valid on 2019-02-03, and the associate value date (which would probably be 2019-02-01, since 2019-02-03 is a sunday...)

I have no idea however how I can do this with the Eloquent QueryBuilder without falling back to doing raw sql queries...

```
$value_date = '2019-02-03';
App\ExchangeRate::where('value_date', function($query) use ($value_date) {
    ... ??? ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where()` can also accept a closure that would allow you to do this:

```
return ExchangeRate::select('currency', 'value_date', 'rate')
    ->where('value_date', function($query) {
        $query->from('exchange_rates AS er')
            ->selectRaw('max(value_date)')
            ->whereColumn('exchange_rates.currency', 'er.currency')
            ->where('value_date', '<=', '2019-02-03');
    })->get();
```

Here's the [output](https://implode.io/HubXz5) of the query.

**Edit**: To assign an alias to the `outer` table, you could do that with the DB Query Builder.

```
return DB::table('exchange_rates AS alias')
    ->select('currency', 'value_date', 'rate')
    ->where('value_date', function($query) {
        $query->from('exchange_rates AS er')
            ->selectRaw('max(value_date)')
            ->whereColumn('alias.currency', 'er.currency')
            ->where('value_date', '<=', '2019-02-03');
    })->get();
```

Comment: So 'exchange_rates.currency' relates to the outer table.  Can I assign an alias explicitely to exchange_rates from the outer query when using the model as a starting point?

Comment: got it, but that means I need to 'know' the table name...  I prefer to start from the model for my queries... thank you though!

Comment: also - other reason why I want to start from my model is that we rely on global scopes a lot; they can not be lost ;-)  When using DB::table(), scopes are being lost...

Comment: `(new ExchangeRate)->getTable()` will output the table name associated with your `ExchangeRate` model :)

Comment: yeah, but I have other reasons not to use DB::table() - I need the scopes applied ;-)  We have some multi-tenant features that we need to keep working ;-)

Comment: Right, but any reason why you would want to alias the `outer` table in this case? Isn't it working? We do alias the `inner` one.

Comment: yeah it works - it's just readability.  On an inner select, I prefer to always explicitely be able to reference a table of the OUTER select; giving it no alias makes me "think" it'll use the inner table instead.  It's working perfectly, so thanks for your feedback - sometimes we just have crazy "believes" that we don"t want to ditch ;-)